# in jqwidgets jquery framework bootstrap integration is my issue for a dropdown

Tags: jqwidget

in jqwidgets jquery framework the bootstrap integration is not working..kindly give the steps

the plugin :

```
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="jqwidgets/styles/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="Jqwidgets/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="Jqwidgets/scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Jqwidgets/scripts/demos.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxcore.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxlistbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxdropdownlist.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Script and the control:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert('hi');
    var source = [
                { html: "<div style='height: 20px; float: left;'><img style='float: left; margin-top: 2px; margin-right: 5px;' src='../../images/numberinput.png'/><span style='float: left; font-size: 13px; font-family: Verdana Arial;'>jqxNumberInput</span></div>", title: 'jqxNumberInput' },
                { html: "<div style='height: 20px; float: left;'><img style='float: left; margin-top: 2px; margin-right: 5px;' src='../../images/progressbar.png'/><span style='float: left; font-size: 13px; font-family: Verdana Arial;'>jqxProgressBar</span></div>", title: 'jqxProgressBar' },
                { html: "<div style='height: 20px; float: left;'><img style='float: left; margin-top: 2px; margin-right: 5px;' src='../../images/calendar.png'/><span style='float: left; font-size: 13px; font-family: Verdana Arial;'>jqxCalendar</span></div>", title: 'jqxCalendar' },
                { html: "<div style='height: 20px; float: left;'><img style='float: left; margin-top: 2px; margin-right: 5px;' src='../../images/button.png'/><span style='float: left; font-size: 13px; font-family: Verdana Arial;'>jqxButton</span></div>", title: 'jqxButton' },
                { html: "<div style='height: 20px; float: left;'><img style='float: left; margin-top: 2px; margin-right: 5px;' src='../../images/dropdownlist.png'/><span style='float: left; font-size: 13px; font-family: Verdana Arial;'>jqxDropDownList</span></div>", title: 'jqxDropDownList' },
                { html: "<div style='height: 20px; float: left;'><img style='float: left; margin-top: 2px; margin-right: 5px;' src='../../images/listbox.png'/><span style='float: left; font-size: 13px; font-family: Verdana Arial;'>jqxListBox</span></div>", title: 'jqxListBox' },
                { html: "<div style='height: 20px; float: left;'><img style='float: left; margin-top: 2px; margin-right: 5px;' src='../../images/tooltip.png'/><span style='float: left; font-size: 13px; font-family: Verdana Arial;'>jqxTooltip</span></div>", title: 'jqxTooltip' },
                { html: "<div style='height: 20px; float: left;'><img style='float: left; margin-top: 2px; margin-right: 5px;' src='../../images/scrollbar.png'/><span style='float: left; font-size: 13px; font-family: Verdana Arial;'>jqxScrollBar</span></div>", title: 'jqxScrollBar' },
                { html: "<div style='height: 20px; float: left;'><img style='float: left; margin-top: 2px; margin-right: 5px;' src='../../images/datetimeinput.png'/><span style='float: left; font-size: 13px; font-family: Verdana Arial;'>jqxDateTimeInput</span></div>", title: 'jqxDateTimeInput' },
                { html: "<div style='height: 20px; float: left;'><img style='float: left; margin-top: 2px; margin-right: 5px;' src='../../images/expander.png'/><span style='float: left; font-size: 13px; font-family: Verdana Arial;'>jqxExpander</span></div>", title: 'jqxExpander' },
                { html: "<div style='height: 20px; float: left;'><img style='float: left; margin-top: 2px; margin-right: 5px;' src='../../images/menu.png'/><span style='float: left; font-size: 13px; font-family: Verdana Arial;'>jqxMenu</span></div>", title: 'jqxMenu' },
            ];

            $("#jqxWidget").jqxDropDownList({ source: source, selectedIndex: 0, theme: "bootstrap" });
});
    </script>

<div id="jqxWidget">


</div>
</div>
```

in the above  code theme:"bootstrap" is been mentioned but the bootstrap is not being applied in the webpage...

Answer (score 0):

You will find working bootstrap examples here:
 http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/twitter/

E.g. navigate to **Responsive Grid Layout**. Then you will find this example and its source: http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/twitter/bootstrap-grid-layout.htm?light